# PHP Stripe - List all SKU's with specific product ID

Tags: php, api

I am looking to list all SKU's from Stripe with a specific product ID. I know how to list all SKU's but not sort them out.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('TESTKEY');

$allSKU = \Stripe\SKU::all(['limit' => 10]);

foreach ($allSKU->autoPagingIterator() as $sku){

     echo "$sku->$id <br />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the data into an array then re-sort the array.

Comment: There is a limit to how many results I can pull at one time. So if I have 100 SKU's that would never work.

Comment: have you reached out to Stripe's support? They have a very good support staff that is available via chat.